# Python Logging log multiple timezone in same message

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging formatter like this:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s \t [ %(asctime)s ] > %(message)s')
```

When it takes log, it will have result like this:

```
2020-08-10 22:21:16,173 [ 2020-08-10 22:21:16,173 ] > Something
```

However, instead of having both time in the same timezone, I want one of them in another timezone. E.g:

```
2020-08-10 22:21:16,173 [ 2020-08-10 18:21:16,173 ] > Something
```

I've tried `logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime`, but it converts both time into the same timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see in the `logging` package code only one converter can be used at a time.
However, you can subclass the `Formatter` class and override the `formatTime` method to use two converters. The resulting time strings should be concatenated and returned.

The `formatTime` docsting says:

> This method can be overridden
> in formatters to provide for any specific requirement, but the
> basic behaviour is as follows: if datefmt (a string) is specified,
> it is used with time.strftime() to format the creation time of the
> record.

Something like this (I didn't run it):

```
def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
    ct_local = time.localtime(record.created)
    ct_gmt =  time.gmtime(record.created)
    if datefmt:
        s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct_local) + '\t[' + time.strftime(datefmt, ct_gmt) + ']'
    else:
        t_local = time.strftime(self.default_time_format, ct_local)
        t_gmt = time.strftime(self.default_time_format, ct_gmt)
        s = self.default_msec_format % (t_local, record.msecs) + '\t[' + self.default_msec_format % (t_gmt, record.msecs) + ']' 
    return s
```

Comment: Worth noting, this solution breaks the conversion formatting separation.

Comment: Thanks @Ferenc Pal! let me test it and get back to you :D